# Are there any chemistry research classification systems?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

There are research classification systems for mathematics ([MSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Subject_Classification)) and physics ([PACS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_and_Astronomy_Classification_Scheme) and subsequently [PhySH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhySH)) which help the researchers to navigate through codes composed by letters/numbers made by associations that specialise in those pieces of human knowledge. Are there any classification systems of research in chemistry?

Comment: I guess I always thought there would be… Although, frankly, PACS is not very useful…

Comment: I'm not sure if it counts as a classification system, but SciFinder can be used to filter research papers based on many criteria. Each chemical has a CAS number as well.